# How to Preserve the Input's Declared Encoding in the Output of javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform? (e.g. avoid UTF-16 changing to UTF-8)

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, xslt

Assuming this input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<test></test>
```

Writing these lines of code :

```
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(/* the above XML*/));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, streamResult);
return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
```

Outputs for me this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test></test>
```

(the declared encoding of UTF-**16** is converted to the default UTF-**8**)

I know I can explicitly ask for UTF-16 output

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-16");
```

**But the question is, how to make the output encoding *automatically* be the same as the input?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible without manually peeking into the input stream first. By the way, if you're using the encoding of the XML header you mustn't use strings, only byte arrays.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why does that requirement exist? The resulting XML should be just as valid if it uses UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'll have to use something more sophisticated than a `StreamSource`. For example, a [`StAXSource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stax/StAXSource.html#StAXSource%28javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader%29) takes an `XMLStreamReader`, which has the [`getCharacterEncodingScheme()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getCharacterEncodingScheme%28%29) method that tells you which encoding the input document used - you can the set that as output enocding.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
// Create an XML Stream Reader
XMLStreamReader xmlSR = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
        .createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(/* the above XML*/));
// Wrap the XML Stream Reader in a StAXSource
StAXSource source = new StAXSource(xmlSR);
// Create a String Writer
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
// Create a Stream Result
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
// Create a transformer
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
// Set STANDALONE based on the source stream
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE,
        xmlSR.isStandalone() ? "yes" : "no");
// Set ENCODING based on the source stream
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,
        xmlSR.getCharacterEncodingScheme());
// Set VERSION based on the source stream
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, xmlSR.getVersion());
// Transform the source stream to the out stream
transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
// Print the results
return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
```

Comment: I am getting: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource

Answer (score 1):

You need to peek into the stream first.
Section F of the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing) gives you an idea how to auto-detect the encoding.

Comment: please don't write your own code to determine the encoding.  it _will_ be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT processor doesn't actually know what the input encoding is (the XML parser doesn't tell it, because it doesn't need to know). You can set the output encoding using xsl:output, but to make this the same as the input encoding you're going to have to discover the input encoding first, for example by peeking at the source file before parsing it.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. After parsing and Infoset building, there is no need for this data, and that is why is not kept as part of the Infoset.